# What does this SQL function do?

Tags: sql-server

I'm not sure if I get this right. Please someone explain to me. I don't know what deatiles should I add to shis function. I gues somwone who knows sql well will know this easily

```
     declare @date      datetime = '2016-05-01',
            @ndays     INT = 11,
            @country     NVARCHAR(2)
    
    BEGIN         
            
           IF @date IS NULL
             BEGIN       
               SET @date = GETDATE();                                                   
             END
            IF @country IS NULL
             BEGIN       
               SET @country = 'HU';                                                     
             END
    
           DECLARE @count      INT  = 1                                                 
           DECLARE @newdate    datetime                                                 
           DECLARE @firstdayofmonth date = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @date), 0) 
    
    
            
           
           WHILE DATEPART(weekday,@firstdayofmonth) in (7,1)                                                                                        
            BEGIN 
              SET @firstdayofmonth = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @firstdayofmonth)                  
            END;
    
           SET @newdate = @firstdayofmonth                                              
    
           WHILE @count < @ndays                                                        
            BEGIN 
    
            SET @newdate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @newdate)                                    
    
            IF (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @newdate) not in (1,7))                               
                SET @count += 1;                                                        
            END  
    
            select @newdate                                                             
      END
```

I get that this is about declaring a date. The firstdayofmonth calculatio is confusing in it.

Comment: please explain what you are trying to do in the code, what output you are expecting and what error/is the problem

Comment: I have edited the tags to change [tag:mysql] to [tag:sql-server]. The syntax you show is not valid for MySQL, but I believe it is for Microsoft SQL Server. Please understand that MySQL and Microsoft are different software products, with different features, including different function syntax.

Comment: What do *you* think it does? What parts don't you understand?

Comment: As a side note, I very much doubt the above needs a `WHILE`. SQL is a set-based language and a `WHILE`/`CURSOR` should only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly no mysql code weekday goes from 0 to 6. Also you can't declare variables that way.

Also you should have posted the whole code.

**AS for your code**:

The first While Clause searches for the first Monday in a Month.

The second counts all Working Days (Monday till Friday) of that chosen Month.

With the first variables, you can manipulate which Month, but what that country has to do with it I can only guess that you have a list of all public holiday fur Hungary.

Answer (score 0):

`@newdate` becomes the first weekday of the month (Monday-Friday). If the month starts on a weekend (Saturday or Sunday), it shifts up until Monday; otherwise it stays the same. As for the second part, `@count` looks like it ends up being the number of weekdays in the first eleven days since the start of the first weekday.